# Replace log files time stamp with empty string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have log files with following format:

```
2014-10-13.log:Mon Oct 13 02:40:11 EDT 2014: log info........
2014-10-14.log:Mon Oct 13 02:40:11 EDT 2014: log info........
```

I am trying to get rid of the log time stamp so that I can only have the log info.

```
sed 's/^2014\-*2014\:$//g'
```

the regular expression doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/^2014.*2014: //' logFile
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I didn't provide the log file at the end of my command. Silly me.. :P